# jQuery changing body's background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is frustrating and I can't figure this out.
I just need to change/toggle back/foreground color 
for the entire body when user clicks on a link, 'theme'.
Following is my html file.

```
...
<style>
    highlight {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.theme').on('click', function () {
            $(document.body).toggleClass("highlight");
            //$(document.body).css({"background-color": "black"});
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I use $().css({...}), it works but when I try to use
class to be able to toggle, it doesn't. Please help.

Comment: `.highlight ` Missng class `.` in `style tag`

Comment: tried with or without . did not work. When I see things through Chrome's developer tools, it seems to tack it onto the body element and take it off when clicked again.

Comment: I tried with or without and it didn't work before but now it does. it's little strange. it works now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Rayon. "highlight" in the style is not a class if missing the period in front. jQuery is not able to toggle the "highlight" class since there's no "highlight" class to toggle. The code works here: http://liveweave.com/T6c7Mz

Comment: just on the side note... which is right? toggleClass(".highlight") or toggleClass("highlight")?

Answer (score 1):

change the following line

```
$(document.body).toggleClass("highlight");
```

with

```
$("body").toggleClass("highlight");
```

Comment: did not work. but it tacks it onto the body element.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

**HTML**

`<a href="#" id="theme">Click Me</a>`

**CSS**

```
body { background-color:red; }
.highlight
 {
  background-color:yellow;  
 }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#theme").click(function() {
$("body").toggleClass("highlight");
```

});

Here is the working code
http://jsfiddle.net/CLwE5/119/